# Python equivalent for PHP's usort()?

Tags: python, sorting

My data structure is a list of tuples in Python, and I'd like to be able to sort the list items by a value contained in their tuples. In PHP, I'd normally create my own sorting function with usort(). Is there an equivalent in Python I could use?

Comment: Use `sort()`. It takes a `key` argument; see the manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give the `sort()` method a `key` function:

```
>>> my_list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
>>> my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> my_list
[(2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4)]
>>>
```

If you need to get a sorted list, instead of sorting *in place*, use the built_in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
[(2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no premade function for doing this, but it can be done fairly easily using [operator module functions](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Operator_Module_Functions) as the key function for sorting. As the code example shows, you can use

```
from operator import itemgetter

tuple_list.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
```

This will sort by the index 1 elements in the tuples.

Answer (score 0):

It's analog:

```
def usort(array, callback):

    from functools import cmp_to_key
    import inspect

    return array.sort(key=cmp_to_key(callback))
```